# FireBase Permiso Denegado al registrar un usuario

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-auth

les cuento que tengo una app de notas conectada a firebase, le cambie las reglas a mi firebase para que sea más seguro pero desde que hice eso al querer registrar un usuario me da un mensaje de permiso denegado, pero lo más raro es que al final si me lo crea ese usuario pero ya que da ese error no va a la pantalla principal ya que cuando te registras debería llevarte directo a la pantalla principal donde estarán tus notas, pero ahora solo se queda ahí en la pantalla de registro.

Foto del error:

[image: Al registrar da error]

Código del método registrar:

```
private void registerUser(final String name, String email, String password) {

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    progressDialog.setMessage(
            getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.procesando_registro));
    progressDialog.show();

    fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        fUsersDatabase
                                .child(Objects.requireNonNull(fAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                                .child("basic").child("name").setValue(name)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                                                    OnBoardingActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                                            finish();
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                                    R.string.usuario_creado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                                    "ERROR: " + Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException())
                                                            .getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                "ERROR: " + Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Reglas de FireBase:

[image]

Les recalco esta parte: **Antes de modificar las reglas no me pasaba este error, no toque nada de mi código solo las reglas de fireBase, estoy abierto a si ustedes ven otra forma de mejorar el código que tengo para que no de ese error. Gracias**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que se porque te pasa eso amigo. Te voy a explicar como puedes organizar tus **reglas** según lo que deseas.

Primero has de tener un registro de todos los **usuarios** con sus datos, para luego poder hacer esa llamada que mencionas en las **Notas**

> Las reglas de **firebase** son una herramienta para poder administrar con precisión quien puede y quien no acceder a una determinada región de tu **base de datos**.

Por tanto siguiendo esa nota te aconsejo tener una base de datos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Esa estructura es solo como método de enseñanza, para que obtengas una idea de como podrías estructurar tus reglas.

Como puedes obsvervar en esta base de datos los **usuarios** se obtienen según si ***uid***, con esto garantizas que cada usuario tenga un único espacio en tu registro y que sea sencillo de acceder.

Para ayudarte con tu pregunta, deseas que solo el usuario que creo las notas sea el que las lea y las escriba pues es muy sencillo si sigues las instrucciones que te deje antes... Te explico:

Para poder lograr esta estructura

```
Notes---
       |
       ---- uid---
                 |
                 ---- Class Nota
```

Debes garantizar pasarle el uid a la referencia. Por ejemplo:

```
DatabaseReference mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference db;
db = mReference.getRoot().child(NOTES_PATH).child(uid);
```

Eso te devolverá lo que contenga ese **uid**, ya sea una clase, un valor, etc.

Comment: creo que eso debe solucionar tu problema, a la hora de meter en la base de datos de usuarios tienes que tener bien definido que solo los usuarios autenticados pueden escribir, si necesitas que agregue algo más me lo comentas salu2

Comment: Tengo una duda, que haces con el índexOn?? o cual es el objetivo del indexOn?

Comment: Es para hacer querys a la bd

Comment: Esta bien, haré lo que me dijiste en tu respuesta y te aviso en un momento si lo logre, gracias saludos

Comment: Gracias Alex, la solución fue solo estructurar bien mi BD como indicaste arriba ahora todo funciona correctamente, gracias!

Comment: de nada me alegra hacer de ayuda... Salu2 :)